# Set string values inside for without knowing names

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find the correct way to set the string values inside the For without knowing the actual numbers. here's what i am trying to do as it was possible in vb6 but not sure using vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

Dim iTest1 As String
Dim iTest2 As String
Dim iTest3 As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For i = 1 To 3

        "iTest" & i = "aaa" & i

    Next

    Debug.Print("iTest1:" & iTest1)
    Debug.Print("iTest2:" & iTest2)
    Debug.Print("iTest3:" & iTest3)
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That wasn't possible in VB6, at least not using that syntax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Arrays instead.

```
Dim iTest(3) As String

For i = 1 To 3
        iTest(i) = "aaa" & i
 Next
```

Or this

```
Dim variables As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

        For i = 1 To 3

        variables("iTest" + i.ToString) = "aaa" & i

    Next

    Console.WriteLine("iTest1:" + variables("iTest1"))
    Console.WriteLine("iTest2:" + variables("iTest2"))
    Console.WriteLine("iTest3:" + variables("iTest3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible, but not really a recommended approach...

If you make the variables **Public**, then you can use the legacy [CallByName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6(v=vs.90).aspx) function brought over from VB6:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public iTest1 As String
    Public iTest2 As String
    Public iTest3 As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            CallByName(Me, "iTest" & i, CallType.Let, "aaa" & i)
        Next

        Debug.Print("iTest1:" & iTest1)
        Debug.Print("iTest2:" & iTest2)
        Debug.Print("iTest3:" & iTest3)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Without CallByName(), this can be accomplished via [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).  Note that this works with **Private or Public** variables:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private iTest1 As String
    Private iTest2 As String
    Private iTest3 As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim T As Type = Me.GetType

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            Dim F As Reflection.FieldInfo = T.GetField("iTest" & i, Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            If Not IsNothing(F) Then
                F.SetValue(Me, "aaa" & i)
            End If
        Next

        Debug.Print("iTest1:" & iTest1)
        Debug.Print("iTest2:" & iTest2)
        Debug.Print("iTest3:" & iTest3)
    End Sub

End Class
```