# vb.net Access a Dim with a string while enumerating a datatable

Tags: vb.net, code-behind

I am trying to update variable while I loop through a datatable
I use Findcontrol if I want to update a label but how do I that for a Dim?

```
    Dim test1 As String = ""
    Dim test2 As String = ""
    Dim test3 As String = ""

    Dim int As Integer = 1

    Do Until int = 4
          "Test" & int = "Value"

           int += 1
    Loop
```

Comment: You don't. The reason you can do that with a `Label` is that a control has a `Name` property and you can use that property to identify a specific control in a parent `Controls` collection. What you are calling "a Dim" is a variable and that is very different. There is no corresponding mechanism.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32856689/2330053)...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a collection like [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) or list:

```
Dim testCollection(3) As String
For i As Int32 = 0 To 3
    testCollection(i) = "Value" & i
Next
```

Now you have a `String()` with 4 elements which you can access via index, for example:

```
Dim test1 As String = testCollection(0) ' "Value0"
```

If you actually don't want to access them by a number but by a name, you should store them in a [`Dictionary(Of String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0). Here is a sample with your commented names:

```
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"db_ma_vsYear", ""}, {"db_en_vsYear", ""}}
```

Now you can access and modify it by name:

```
dict("db_ma_vsYear") = "New Value"
Dim db_ma_vsYear As String = dict("db_ma_vsYear") ' New Value
```

Comment: I did the above as an example but I have variables aleady declared and I want to access them not by number but with two characters
db_ma_vsYear or db_en_vsYear

Comment: `db_ma_vsYear` is not a character but a string. So you want to access string variables by name that is known at runtime?

Comment: @GarethFairclough: then use a dictionary, edited the answer